# Does it matter which recording software I use?

Tags: recording, software, audacity

Supposing the mic, cable, audio interface, recording computer, sample rate and bit depth etc. are all exactly the same, should there be any difference whether I record with Cubase or with Audacity? I'm only talking about recording here, not mixing or adding any effects.

ltdr: does the recorded data depend only on the hardware & settings, or will recording with the freeware Audacity might damage the quality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not matter in terms of exactly how the audio is written to the disk. The interface you use will make a difference with that. When you start mixing the audio then the software can make a difference although the differences between different DAWs is getting harder to hear all the time (or maybe I'm just getting too old to hear it?). Also the included plug-ins will be different which will affect the mixing a lot.

But for the recording phase, it's all about the interface (and everything before it, of course).